# Pizzas for eXide

Tags: html, xpath, xquery

```
<pizzeria>
    <pizzas>
        <pizza id="p001">
            <nombre>Carbonara</nombre>
            <precio>8.45</precio>
            <disponible>si</disponible>
        </pizza>
        <pizza id="p002">
            <nombre>Barbacoa</nombre>
            <precio>9.25</precio>
            <disponible>si</disponible>
        </pizza>
        <pizza id="p003">
            <nombre>Gourmet</nombre>
            <precio>7.95</precio>
            <disponible>no</disponible>
        </pizza>
        <pizza id="p004">
            <nombre>Boloñesa</nombre>
            <precio>10.45</precio>
            <disponible>si</disponible>
        </pizza>
    </pizzas>
</pizzeria>
```

I need to make this phrase:
Ofrecemos “pizza counting” pizzas desde “minimum price”€ (“name of the cheapest pizza”). Only available pizzas will be taken into account (they contain the value “si” in the disponible element).

The result must be "Ofrecemos 3 pizzas desde 8.45€(Carbonara)"

I tried this code:

```
<table>
 {let $i:=min(doc("/db/exercise/pizzeria.xml")//pizzas/pizza/precio)
 for $e in doc("/db/exercise/pizzeria.xml")//pizzas
 where $e/pizza/precio=$i
 return
   (<caption>
      Ofrecemos {count($e/pizza[disponible="si"])} pizzas desde {min($e/pizza[.//disponible="si"]/precio)}€ ({$e/pizza[.//disponible="si"]/nombre/text()})
   </caption>)
 }
</table>
```

Sadly, it doesn't work.
Please, if you are going to help me, try with the simplest answer. I'm new and I don't know much about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<caption>
 {
     let $h := /pizzeria/pizzas/pizza[disponible = "si"]    
     let $i := min($h/precio)
     let $j := ($h[precio = $i]/nombre)[1]
     let $k := count($h)
     return
        concat("Ofrecemos ", $k, " pizzas desde ", $i, "€ ", $j)
 }
 </caption>
```

fiddle https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDbxkY

Made a modification to select one name in case if you find multiple pizzas with the same lowest value.

===========================

As for your xquery:

1. `let $i:=min(//pizzas/pizza/precio)` points to 7.95.
2. `for $e in //pizzas` returns  `<pizzas>` element(s).
3. `for $e in //pizzas where $e/pizza/precio=$i` the where clause is always true and will return the parent `<pizzas>` element which contains the `<pizza>` elements.
4. your version modified: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDbxkY/11

Comment: Can you tell me which was my mistake?

Comment: Are you mocking me?

Comment: @BL, ??? no. not sure why you felt that way. Please see the update.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "the where clause is always true". I tried this in a similar exercise and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 solution :

```
concat('"Ofrecemos ',count(//pizza[disponible[.="si"]])," pizzas desde ",//precio[following-sibling::disponible[.="si"]][not(.>//precio[following-sibling::disponible[.="si"]])]/text(),"€(",//precio[following-sibling::disponible[.="si"]][not(.>//precio[following-sibling::disponible[.="si"]])]/preceding-sibling::*[1]/text(),')"')
```

Output : `"Ofrecemos 3 pizzas desde 8.45€(Carbonara)"`